# Akamai Media Services Live Api: limit results from stream query

Tags: akamai

I am trying to get a list of our streams from Akamai's Media Services API v1; however, I'm only getting a 504 Gateway Timeout. I believe this is due to the amount of streams being queried for, as I can get a single stream when I give the ID for the GET stream/{streamId} endpoint.

I am using the **edgegrid** node module and have tried adding query parameters such as limit, pageSize/page-size, and stream-name/streamName to limit my results to no avail.

Is there a way to limit the results in a query for this API?

---

edit:
We are using v1 of the API

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [v2 of the API](https://developer.akamai.com/api/media_delivery/msl_stream_provisioning/v2.html#getstreamprovisioningendpoints), it should automatically return the results paged. The API endpoint /config-media-live/v2/msl-origin/streams includes the ability to specify query string parameters `page` and `pageSize`. `page` is an integer that tells the API which page number to return. `pageSize` is also an integer referring to the number of entries the page should contain.

Example: `/config-media-live/v2/msl-origin/streams?page=2&pageSize=10&sortKey=createdDate&sortOrder=ASC`

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are using v1 for the time being. I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: v1 should have the same paging capability (https://developer.akamai.com/api/media_delivery/msl_stream_provisioning/v1.html#getstreamprovisioningendpoints), but as v1 is deprecated, you may have hit a bug with the API that likely won't be fixed. I would encourage you to look at moving to v2 if possible.